# Как не загружать оперативку при парсинге?

Tags: python, парсер, telegram, telethon

Есть скрипт который парсит тг каналы,но проблема в том что он прежде чем записать на диск,выгружает данные в оперативную память. Можно ли как-то исключить из процесса выгрузку в оперативку и сразу загружать все на диск? (Скрипт работает через telethon)

Всем спасибо :)

Comment: а чем проблема загрузки в ОЗУ? Большая страница? Или несколько потоков?

Comment: Много данных, озу не вытягивает, парсер на сервере лежит и жрет 3гб оперативы

Comment: переписывай все списки на генераторы и пиши по одному файлу